# Prove that $\sin(2\arcsin x + \arccos x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to prove that
$$
\sin(2\arcsin x + \arccos x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}.
$$
Let $\alpha = 2 \arcsin x$ and $\beta = \arccos x$; meaning $\sin\alpha = \frac{x}{2}, \cos\beta = x$. We know that:
$$
\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta.
$$
Finding $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$:
$$\begin{align}
\cos\alpha & = \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}, \\[0.1in]
\sin\beta & = \sqrt{1-x^2}.
\end{align}$$
So plugging everything in:
$$\begin{align}
\sin(2\arcsin x + \arccos x) & = \frac{x}{2} \cdot x + \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2} \cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}\\[0.1in]
& = \frac{x^2 + \sqrt{4-x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}.
\end{align}$$
But this doesn't seem to lead to the right side. Is my method incorrect?

Comment: $\alpha = 2\arcsin x$ means that $x = \sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$, not that $\frac{x}{2} = \sin\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\arcsin x+\arccos x=\frac\pi2$$

So, we have $$\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\arcsin x\right)=\cos(\arcsin x)$$

Now [$\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. How?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345077/cos-arcsinx-sqrt1-x2-how)

Comment: Why does $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin x)=\cos(\arcsin x)$?

Comment: @hohner, $\sin(\pi/2+y)=\cos y$ as sine ratio is positive in the second quadrant

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way of proving this? I'm studying $R\cos(x\pm\alpha)$ and inverse trig functions at the moment :)

Comment: Also, why does $\arcsin x=\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: @hohner, Have not you noticed the proof?

Comment: I just don't understand the $\arcsin x = \arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$ part - the rest I understand.

Comment: @hohner, Edited the answer. The statement is valid only if $x\ge0$, else $\arcsin x=-\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha=2\arcsin x$  means that $x=\sin(\frac\alpha2)$, not that $\frac x2=\sin\alpha$

$\frac\alpha2=\arcsin x$

$x=\sin(\frac\alpha2)$

an alternate and faster way is to use

$\arcsin x+\arccos x=\frac\pi2$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\sin(2\arcsin x + \arccos x) - \sqrt{(1-x^2)}=\sin(\arcsin x + \frac\pi 2) - \sqrt{(1-x^2)}=\cos(\arcsin x)-\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$.

$f'(x)=0$, hence $f$ is constant.

In particular $f(x)=f(0)=0$